# Angular router link not working with unit tests

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Angular router link works with ng serve but when running unit tests e.g. ng test I get the error below.

**This is my link in my html:**

```
<a [routerLink]="['/about']" class="button large" [myHighlight]="'gold'" title="About">About</a>
```

**This is the error message:**

> Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it
>   isn't a known property of 'a'.

**This is my module for this component:**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";

import { HomeComponent } from "./home.component";
import { UserService } from "../../services/user.service";
import { HighlightDirective } from "../../directives/highlight.directive";

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [HomeComponent, HighlightDirective],
  exports: [HomeComponent],
  providers: [UserService]
})
export class HomeModule {
}
```

RouterModule is imported so not sure why the unit tests are unhappy.

**This is my unit test for the component:**

```
import { TestBed, async, inject } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { HttpClient, HttpHandler } from "@angular/common/http";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from "./home.component";
import { UserService } from "../../services/user.service";
import { User } from "../../models/user.model";
import { HighlightDirective } from "../../directives/highlight.directive";

class RouterStub {
  navigateByUrl(url: string) { return url; }
}

describe("HomeComponent", () => {
  let userService;
  let homeComponent;
  let fixture;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterModule],
      declarations: [
        HomeComponent,
        HighlightDirective
      ],
      providers: [
        HttpClient,
        HttpHandler,
        UserService,
        { provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub }
      ]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(inject([UserService], service => {
    userService = service;
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
    homeComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
  }));

  it("should return array of users as observable", async(() => {
    // Arrange
    const response: User[] = [];
    spyOn(userService, "getUsers").and.returnValue(of(response));

    // Act
    homeComponent.getUsers();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // Assert
    expect(homeComponent.listOfUsers).toEqual(response);
  }));

});
```

**This is my component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { UserService } from "../../services/user.service";
import { User } from "../../models/user.model";

@Component({
  selector: "home-users",
  templateUrl: "./home.component.html"
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() userEvent = new EventEmitter();
  private listOfUsers: User[];

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router) {}

  // Lifecycle Hook (8 exist)
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers(): void {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
      this.listOfUsers = users;

      this.userEvent.emit("getUsers - complete");
    });
  }
}
```

**Current Error:**

> Error: No provider for ActivatedRoute!

Comment: I don't see why they wouldn't work together. The error message rather indicates that the `RouterModule` is not imported in the module that contains above code.

Comment: Can you post some more snippet of your code, to make it more meaningful and easy to debug.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've added the RouterModule.

Comment: I've added the module above. I get this error when I run ng test with karma.

The actual code works fine. Only breaks unit tests

Comment: Looks good. Can you try to reproduce the problem in Plunker? I'm sure this should just work.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've added the unit test above. I've iscolated the issue further. Seems the routerLink doesnt work well when the components unit test runs only. Seems like maybe my unit test is missing something?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've added my component above as well. This issue only occurs when I run my unit tests

Comment: I'm not familiar with testing in TS, but I think that the `HomeModule` should be imported `TestBed.configureTestingModule({ imports: [HomeModule, RouterModule], ...
 `and also `providers: [...]` should contain ` { provide: Router,         useClass: RouterStub},` See also https://angular.io/guide/testing#routed-component

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've read that link and stubbed the router in the unit test. I've updated my code above but now get a new unit test error: "Error: No provider for ActivatedRoute!"

Comment: Add a provider `{ provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: ActivatedRouteStub },` and add the `ActivatedRouteStub` class explained in the docs.

Comment: This seems very over the top for a simple unit test. I stubbed ActivatedRouteStub (this stub in the docs is a lot of code) and now its asking for LocationStrategy.